# How to use @SuppressFBWarnings correctly to ignore printStackTrace findbugs warning

Tags: java, findbugs, printstacktrace

In my junit 4 test code I am using test rules that contain code like this:

```
catch (Throwable t) {
   t.printStackTrace();
   throw t;
}
```

Findbugs complains about this, and rightfully so - this should not be done in our production code. In this instance, however, I think the usage is justified, and I try to use the @SuppressFBWarnings annotation to silence findbugs. However, neither

```
@SuppressFBWarnings
private void warmUp() throws Throwable {
```

nor

```
@SuppressFBWarnings("IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_PRINTSTACKTRACE")
private void warmUp() throws Throwable {
```

nor

```
@SuppressFBWarnings({"IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_PRINTSTACKTRACE"})
private void warmUp() throws Throwable {
```

have the desired result.

How do I use @SuppressFBWarnings correctly to surpress the warning?

Comment: The second option is correct. Did you recompile?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I couldn't make it work and used loggers for the moment. But it helps me to know what should work,  if I need to deal with a similar problem.

Answer (score 11):

By using the following gradle dependency for the FindBugs annotations:

```
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:3.0.1'
```

Here is what should work:

```
@SuppressFBWarnings(value = "IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_PRINTSTACKTRACE", justification = "Document why this should be ignored here")
private void warmUp() throws Throwable {}
```